# Is there a reason Harvey Bullock in Batman TAS violates the One Steve Limit?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe, batman-the-animated-series

So there is already a very influential Harvey (or two) in the Batman universe. Paul Dini added a few characters in to the DCAU, including Harley Quinn, Renee Montoya, and a few others I'm probably forgetting.

However, there is also a character who violates a very important rule, [The One Steve Limit](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OneSteveLimit), that being the Detective Harvey Bullock. Has Dini or another creative influence in the DCAU ever commented on why they chose to name this character Harvey? Especially when the other Harvey is *also* a legal professional?

Comment: Don't think this violates the rule, since Bullock is almost always referred to by his last name.

Comment: DC clearly doesn't care about this "rule". See also: the Marthas.

Comment: Because they love hearing Kevin Conroy say "Harvey".

Comment: Note: Two-Face was originally Harvey *Kent*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That rule was already broken well before Dini. Harvey Bullock was introduced in the comics, back in 1974 in Detective Comics #441. Also, in the intro to the TV Tropes articles you linked, you'll notice it specifically mentions the DC universe as one of those places where name duplication is likely to happen, due to its size.

Comment: Shoot - I could have sworn he was created for the DCAU. Oh well, you've prompted me to ask another question! http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150917/is-there-a-list-of-the-characters-that-paul-dini-created-for-the-dcau

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this particular example does not violate the rule. The villian's name is Two-Face and while Batman does call him "Harvey", in many media he is referred to as "Harvey Dent".