# Is there a list of the characters that Paul Dini created for the DCAU?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe

In Batman-TAS several new characters are created. The Most famous obviously is Harley Quinn, but others such as Renee Montoya are also newcomers. Is there a list of new characters that were created just for the DCAU?

Comment: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Paul_Dini/Creator

Comment: Even maybe better than Valorum’s list is a sibling: https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/DCAU_influences_on_mainstream_comics